# Trying to determine how to change border color on input type textbox in google script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am trying to determine how to change the border on an textbox in a sidebar. if I used the div ID (myDiv) it seems to work. When I use the text ID (toggleit) it is not working. Here is the code.

HTML

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <style>
        .error {  
          width: 125px;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 2px solid red;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f8f8f8;
        }
        .myStyle {
          width: 125px;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 2px solid green;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f8f8f8;
        }
        </style>
      <body>
        <div >
          <div id="myDiv">
          <input type="text" class="myStyle" id="toggleit" name="toggleit" placeholder="toggle to red"><br>
          </div>
          <button onclick="toggleTest()">toggle</button>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script>
      function toggleTest() {
        document.getElementById("toggleit").classList.toggle("error");
      }
      </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove or toggle the myStyle class too.

```js
function toggleTest() {
        document.getElementById("toggleit").classList.toggle("error");
        document.getElementById("toggleit").classList.toggle("myStyle");
      }
```

```css
.error {  
          width: 125px;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 2px solid red;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f8f8f8;
        }
        .myStyle {
          width: 125px;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 2px solid green;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f8f8f8;
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <div >
          <div id="myDiv">
          <input type="text" class="myStyle" id="toggleit" name="toggleit" placeholder="toggle to red"><br>
          </div>
          <button onclick="toggleTest()">toggle</button>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: Adding the second toggle worked. I left myStyle in there because I use it for other  input items.